# Какое применение может иметь машинное обучение для реального бизнеса?

Tags: машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Какое можно придумать применение машинному обучению, чтобы оно помогло реальному бизнесу? Например рекомендательную систему на киносайте, которая будет по эмоциональной окраске отзывов к просмотренным пользователем фильмам рекомендовать похожие фильмы.

Comment: Ответ на вопрос содержится в самом вопросе?

Comment: Нет, это только пример

Comment: @user265001 да, потому что это ответ.

Comment: Любое, которое прийдет к вам на ум. Возможности МО безграничны.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч смелое, но увы неверное утверждение. Пока что МО не способно на факторизацию в целых быстрее имеющихся реализаций.

Comment: Понятно что обширны, но придумать то, что реально могло бы помочь бизнесу и повысить его эффективность - не получается

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Лично я считаю это утверждение абсолютно верным, более того это направление стремительно развевается, и не возможное сегодня уже станет возможным завтра. И даже если учитывать то состояние МО которе есть на данный момент я вижу очень много вариантов которые можно применить в направлении бизнеса. На эту тему спорить нет смысла, у каждого человека свое мнение.

Comment: Игорь, ну помогите задавшему вопрос, если вам не сложно)

Comment: @user265001, вы можете описать (поверхностно) чем примерно занимается фирма?

Comment: Моя задача просто предложить решение, фирмы конкретной нет, это проходит в рамках кейс-чемпионата, нужно взять любую фирму и придумать как бы ей помогло МО

Comment: `"нужно взять любую фирму и придумать как бы ей помогло МО"` -- с любой не получится. Нужна фирма, руководство которой имеет хорошие завязки с лицами, распределяющими бюджет. При правильном подходе можно получить неплохой профит.

Answer (score 3):

Любая задача МО требует приличного набора данных и если у фирмы такой набор данных существует то открываются самые различные варианты.

Примеры:

- производство чего угодно - если есть система датчиков (сенсоров) и статистика по отказам/нештатным ситуациям, то можно построить модель, которая будет предсказывать такие ситуации **до** того как они случатся
- контроль качества (классификация) продукции при помощи фото/видео и соответствующей модели
- предсказание количества (регрессия) заказов в зависимости от ...
- предсказание вероятности (классификация) мошенничества при онлайн заказах/проведении финансовых транзакций/оплате кредиткой/выдаче кредитов/etc.
- мониторинг сложных IT систем/комплексов и предсказание того, что скоро случится "minor or major fuckup"
- таргетированная реклама в онлайн магазинах
- адаптивные системы обучения в школе/универе, которые подбирают индивидуальные задания и даже предлагают дальнейшее направление обучения
- то чем давно занимаются гос. структуры - мониторинг социальных сетей и поиск (классификация) террористов и предсказание массовых волнений

и т.д.